# Evaluating solutions numerically to the following equations

Tags: numerical-methods

How would one use numerical methods to find solutions to the following equations:
$$\frac{2(b^3-a^3)}{3(b-a)^2}=e-1$$
$$\big(\sqrt{e^{2}+1}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{e^{2}+1}-1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{e^{2}+1}+1)\big)-\big(\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)\big)=\\ \frac{1}{4(b-a)}\bigg( \operatorname{arcsinh}(2b)+2b\sqrt{4b^2+1}-\operatorname{arcsinh}(2a)-2a\sqrt{4a^2+1}\bigg) $$

I understand it would be the intersect between to functions of $x$ and $y$ namely $f(x,y)=\frac{y^3-x^3}{y-x}$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{3}{2}(e-1)$. I can plug this into wolfram alpha to receive the solutions and the following
[image]

I am told to evaluate this numerically it is necessary to create two multi variable functions out of the above two and minimise the function $\Phi(a,b)$. After this create a contour plot of $\Phi(a,b)$ and use the Newton Rhaphson method.

\begin{equation}
    f(a,b)=  \frac{2(b^3-a^3)}{3(b-a)^2}-e+1=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{bigeq2}
\begin{aligned}
    g(a,b)=\big(\sqrt{e^{2}+1}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{e^{2}+1}-1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{e^{2}+1}+1)\big)-\big(\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)\big)-\\ \frac{1}{4(b-a)}\bigg( \operatorname{arcsinh}(2b)+2b\sqrt{4b^2+1}-\operatorname{arcsinh}(2a)-2a\sqrt{4a^2+1}\bigg)=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \Phi(a,b)=\big[f(a,b)\big]^2+\big[g(a,b\big]^2
\end{equation}

Comment: Is there a square in the denominator or is there no power?

Comment: @LutzLehmann no power in the denominator of the second equation

Comment: If I had to solve $a^2+ab+b^2=c(b-a)$ or $x^2+xy+y^2=z$, $c$ or $z$ constant(?), then I would just apply the solution formula for quadratic equations.

Comment: But then why are you pretending that they are the same thing when they are not?

Comment: @LutzLehmann what would you do about $b^3-a^3$

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am trying to find $a$ and $b$. Be more specific please.

Comment: @hwood87 Are these two separate equations, or you want to find solutions satisfying both at the same time?

Comment: I used the binomial identity $b^3-a^3=(b-a)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ which in both cases considerably reduces the degree of the expression. What remains is the equation for an ellipsis, if there are real solutions at all.

Answer (score 1):

By the following

$$\frac{y^3-x^3}{y-x}=\frac{3}{2}(e-1)=a>0$$

by $y\neq x$ we obtain

$$y^2+xy+x^2=a$$

$$ \iff\left(\frac y {\sqrt a}\right)^2+\left(\frac y {\sqrt a}\right)\left(\frac x {\sqrt a}\right)+\left(\frac x {\sqrt a}\right)^2=1$$

which is an [ellipse](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2%2Bxy%2Bx%5E2%3D1) which, with exclusion of the points with $y=x$, is the solution.

Comment: How would I find the solution with the second equation?

Comment: @hwood87 Do you mean with $y^2+xy+x^2=a$?

Comment: No sorry, with the equation: $$\big(\sqrt{e^{2}+1}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{e^{2}+1}-1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{e^{2}+1}+1)\big)-\big(\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)\big)=\\ \frac{1}{4(b-a)}\bigg( \operatorname{arcsinh}(2b)+2b\sqrt{4b^2+1}-\operatorname{arcsinh}(2a)-2a\sqrt{4a^2+1}\bigg) $$

Comment: @hwood87 : Could you explain how you got that expression, it might be an error in formulating the problem in the CAS. And even if it is correct, this is now a transcendental equation, not a simplification from the original algebraic equation.